# How can I move my Form Processor configuration between two sites and/or reorder my actions?

Tags: export, form-processor, action-provider

I see an **Export** link when I go to **Administer menu » Automation » Form Processors**, but it seems like you need to write an extension to move the form between sites.  Is this my only option?

As a related question, can I reorder my actions?

Answer (score 4):

I deleted my old answer because there's a much simpler one now: Use the **Export** link next to the processor you want to copy, and use **Import Processor** on the other site to bring it in.

If you want to make a copy on the same site for testing purposes, open the exported file and change the *name* and *title* values at the top.  Note that the *name* can only have lowercase letters and underscores, whereas the *title* can be whatever you want.

Reordering actions is a built-in feature now and doesn't require any trickery.

[image]

Comment: good to know Jon G could answer your question - suspect not many other folk could